# Произведение элементов массивов

Tags: c#

Что я делаю не так? Заданы два двумерных массива размерности N*M (элементы - случайные числа). Вывести на экран произведение элементов заданных массивов.

```
Random ran = new Random();

        int[,] m1 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] m2 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] m3 = new int[3, 3];
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
        {

            for (int je = 0; je < 3; je++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    int sk = 0;
                    sk += m1[m, je] * m2[m, je];
                    m3[m, je] = sk;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        //    }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[,] m1 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] m2 = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] m3 = new int[3, 3];
        Random ran = new Random();

        // Заполнение случайными числами
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {

            for (int je = 0; je < 3; je++) {
                m1[m, je] = ran.Next(10); // ran.Next(максимально допустимое значение);
                m2[m, je] = ran.Next(10);
            }
        }

        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
            for (int je = 0; je < 3; je++) {
                m3[m, je] = m1[m, je] * m2[m, je]; // Произведение матриц
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Произведение двумерных матриц m1 и m2:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Console.Write(m3[i, j] + " "); // вывод в консоль
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Огроменное, спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Человек вас выручил и даже не получил плюсига =(

Comment: А что за плюсики? Я очень благодарна за помощь!!! Еще раз большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы не заполняете массивы случайными данными.  Массивы не инициализированы и Вы скорее всего видите ошибку сразу при запуске (если это Java, как я понял).
[добавлено]

```
Random ran = new Random();
    int[,] m1 = new int[3, 3];
    int[,] m2 = new int[3, 3];
    int[,] m3 = new int[3, 3];
    int sk=0;
    for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
    {
        for (int je = 0; je < 3; je++)
        {
            m1[m, je]=ran.Next(1000);
            m2[m, je]=ran.Next(1000);
            m3[m, je] = m1[m, je] * m2[m, je];
            sk+= m3[m, je];
            Console.WriteLine(m3[m, je]);
        }
    }
    //    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Это мой первый опыт писать на c#, но мне кажется должно быть примерно хотя бы так. (не проверял, ибо нет IDE соответствующей).
[/добавлено]

Comment: Судя по `Console.WriteLine();`, это C#, а не Java.

Comment: не суть, не видно инициализации массива

Comment: да это си шарп, а как исправить??

Comment: Вот ошибка в словечке rnd не пойму чем заменить?

Comment: @Мария1233333 , исправил

Comment: блин что то там не то на консоле получается...Щас по-русски попробую объяснить (я совсем плохо в программировании): мне надо, чтоб, например, вышли в консоле: первая матрица, вторая матрица и третья.  третья матрица должна состоять из элементов 1-го массива * на элементы 2-го массива.